# How to configure the pylintrc config file on my Mac system

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pylint

I was getting a Warning: **Config file not used, Using default configuration** when i ran pylint 
I ran pylint--generate-rcfile> ~/.pylintrc.
then i got two warning messages :
**Warning: option include-ids is deprecated and ignored.
Warning: option symbols is deprecated and ignored.**

I solved these errors by commenting out the below line in pylintrc 
    #include-ids

Comment: did you take a look at ~/.pylintrc ? Notice the leading dot means the file is hidden under Unix systems, so probably that Finder won't show it by default

Comment: @sthenault- I found the Pylintrc file and edited to suit my needs. I silenced those two errors by Commenting out #include-ids in the pylintrc file